# When does Peter Mayhew appear in Fanboys?

Tags: casting, fanboys

Both [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489049/characters/nm0562679?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t43) and [Letterboxd](https://letterboxd.com/film/fanboys/) list Peter Mayhew as appearing in *Fanboys* (2009) as himself. Which part of the movie was he in?